# Can't use mongo shell on Windows and interact with MongoDB from command line

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I can't use the mongos shell and interact with the MongoDB databases. I'm using Windows 10 Home.

I installed MongoDB locally, version 6.0, using most of the instructions found here: https://medium.com/@LondonAppBrewery/how-to-download-install-mongodb-on-windows-4ee4b3493514

This is my folder for MongoDB:
[image]

I used this in the vim:
alias mongod="/c/Program\ files/MongoDB/Server/6.0/bin/mongod.exe"

alias mongos="/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/6.0/bin/mongos.exe"

I followed these steps:

1- Go to this PC

2- Right click and go to properties

3- Go to "Advanced System Settings"

4- Go to "Environment Variables"

5- Click the "Path" in User variable then click "Edit"

6- Click "New" and add "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin"

7- Click "ok" "ok" "ok"

8- Now restart the hyper terminal

9- Type mongod

Instead of doing it for User Variable, I also did it for System Variables, as an alternative. I get this when I run mongod when I have it in System Variables:
[image]
I get something similar when I did it for User Variables, and when I did NOT do it for either User or System Variables.

I believe Hyper should say: waiting for connections on port 27017.

But when I open a new tab in Hyper, and try to run mongos, mongo, and show dbs. I get this:
[image]

While MongoDB is running, in the new tab I should get a prompt after running mongos.

I'm new to this, so please accept my apologies if I did not question this correctly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `mongos` is completely different thing than mongo shell

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots use formatted text see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: `mongosh` is the new shell.
`mongo` is the legacy shell that no longer ships
`mongos` is for routing queries in sharded clusters ([more here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongos/))

Comment: Yes, mongosh works! Now my problem is when I run mongod, I still get that strange response. Should say works on port 27017